# CSS grid - 1fr col keeps getting cut-off

Tags: css, css-grid

I can't get this css grid to do these 2 things..

1. Value column should always show the entire string, not wrap, and not overflow
2. The hearts column should always stay lined up vertically

Here's an explanation of the problem in an image:

I've been working on this for too long, thank you for helping me!!! <3

---

Codepen simplified down: https://codepen.io/naaadz/pen/OJQZvgB

This is what I have to start with:

```
grid-template-columns: auto 150px auto 1fr;
```

[image]

Comment: Need the code. Please post an [example] in a stack snippet `<>`.

Comment: @Kameron I just added a simplified codepen above, also here: https://codepen.io/naaadz/pen/OJQZvgB  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that it is possible with your current HTML structure.

If you change the grid element to hold your columns, you can achieve it.
Currently, you are having a lot of grids with a single row.

Below is an example of what I mean.
You can change the first column width to `auto`.
I saw that you are limiting it to 150px, so I used the `minmax()` property.

```css
.box {
  width: 300px;
  background: lightgray;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(40px, 150px) 1fr;
  gap: 10px;
  padding: 3px 5px;
  align-items: center;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.font-icon {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.value {
  text-align: right;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.truncate {
  display: -webkit-box !important;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="box">
  <div class="item">
    <i class="font-icon material-icons">circle</i>
    <span class="name truncate">Some value here</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <i class="font-icon material-icons">favorite</i>
    <span class="value item-right">16,000 UNITS</span>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <i class="font-icon material-icons">circle</i>
    <span class="name truncate">Some longer value here longer</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <i class="font-icon material-icons">favorite</i>
    <span class="value item-right">33,000 PPL</span>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <i class="font-icon material-icons">circle</i>
    <span class="name truncate">Some other value</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <i class="font-icon material-icons">favorite</i>
    <span class="value item-right">23,000,000 PPL</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: wow, thank you so much for this option!!

each row has to be a single item due to how it's received from an API, but i can def put two flex items next to eachother like this, i didn't think of trying this.

Again, thank you kind stranger!